# How to find date/time used by Cassandra

Tags: linux, time, cassandra

Earlier this morning I noticed that one of the nodes in our Cassandra cluster is writing logs an hour in the future, despite the date/time being correct on the OS. A couple of other nodes I checked via logs appear to be writing logs at the correct time.

I now need to go through and check each node in our 80 node cluster and ensure cassandra is running on the correct time, problem being is some of the nodes don't write to the logs very often as they aren't doing much... the question is, is there some form of tool/utility (ie nodetool) that can tell me the time that cassandra is running on?

All the systems date/times are correct, ntpdate cron in place has been for a while. Servers are set to Belize timezone to avoid DST changes so its nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear there is no way to find out the time Cassandra is using other than examining the log files and looking at the time stamps of messages as they are appended to the log

```
tail -f /path/to/cassie/log
```

is best way to do this.